# Simulation LTSpice Miller plateau and reverse recovery diode

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice

I would like to do a simulation in order to better understand the losses in switching power supply. I m trying to a simulation with the following circuits :

[image]

I'm working at very high frequency in order to better see the effect of the reverse recovery diode. Nevertheless, in any case I have a problem that I do not understand. Why my Drain voltage of the MOSFET is never near to 0 V ?

[image]

I'm totaly a beginner on LTspice...

Thank you very much and have a nice day !

Comment: Did you happen to notice that I_D is either 1A or -5A? That means the diode does not have enough time to stop conducting and the switching frequency is too fast for that diode's reverse recovery time.

Comment: Run the simulation out to 1us or more, by that time enough charge has flowed out of the diode that it starts to establish a depletion region, but it remains too slow to be considered good at this frequency.

Comment: Thank you very much !